# Can't get my Java EE application client working

Tags: jakarta-ee, client, websphere

I am trying to write a Java EE application client for Websphere 7 to access EJBs that are deployed on a WebSphere server and I can't seem to be able to resolve the EJB using JNDI (I get 'Name comp/env/ejb not found in context "java:"'.

I created the project as an "Application Client Project" in RBD 7.5 and I am using a "WebSphere Application Server v.7.0 Application Client" to run it.

I tried both (but not at the same time) specifying the provider URL when creating the initial context and providing the information in the run configuration, it made no difference.

I'm probably missing something very simple.

By the way, does the launchclient have to be run on the WebsShere server or can I recopy it on another server?

Comment: Post your stack-trace and the logs. There's a good chance it will have the information you're seeking. Because of security concerns sometimes the client exceptions are completely unhelpful. Odds are your security isn't set up right OR you've turned it on and had no idea you did so.

Comment: Hi! The log is here: http://pastebin.com/uEP8MesV and there's no error before this (just component initialization) and no error after this. The NullPointerException (and most likely the invocation error) are AFAIK caused by the fact that I am returned a null but haven't trapped it (since this is test code). Do I have to redo Ejb refs like in the Ejb project and if so how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it looks like you're getting somewhere!

***Sidebar:*** this is probably the most frustrating part of setting up an application server as the documenation is sub-par and the tutorials are usually aimed at people who have done it before. I'm more of a JBoss guy and I really hope someone with more WebSphere knowledge jumps in to help as they probably know the answer off the top of their heads, where all I can do is push you in a direction I *think* it is.

Here's an example of my multi-EE context lookup:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T getObjectFromContext(Class<T> clazz, Namespace namespace)
{
    // java:app/ProductionEJB/OptionsDao!com.danielbchapman.production.beans.SomeDaoRemote
    String lookup;
    if(JEE6)
        lookup = "java:global/" + namespace.toEnterpriseSix() + "/"
                + clazz.getSimpleName().replaceAll("Remote", "") + "!" + clazz.getName();
    else
        lookup = "ProductionEE5/" + clazz.getSimpleName().replaceAll("Remote", "") + "/remote";

    T ret = (T) getObjectFromContext(lookup);
    return ret;
}
```

You can see the context string (JBoss7/EE6) is:

`java:/global/#{JAR_NAME}/#{IMPLEMENTATION_CLASS}!#{REMOTE_INTERFACE}`

For my EE5 lookup (JBoss 5.1GA) is:

`#{EAR_NAME}/#{IMPLEMENTATION_CLASS}`

What you need to do to make this simple is jump into your administration tool and look at your deployment. You'll see the context and generally speaking it tends to be a little different for each implementation. There is a standard and as far as I can tell everyone has their own opinion on it. (Ignore my "Namespace" class, it basically just has more information whether it is `java:app` or `java:global`.

Post more of your information and I'll try to push you in the right direction. Also, look for a tutorial on it. I'm sure it is something trivial.

Comment: Wow.. talking about documentation is subbar and tutorials are aimed for someone done it before.  Lots of FUD being throw around.

Comment: Its awful. Not to beat up on Websphere but I switched to JBoss because of the documentation. Context lookups were a major part of that decision.

Comment: Interesting.  If you have bought the software, you get access to IBM Support.  They'll give you answers in 4 hour time windows (ranges).   Also funny you say documents.... there are tons of pages on the infocenter and a lot of white papers and redbooks.   Not to rag but it doesn't seem like you know how to navigate for info for the product.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't commenting on the fact that documentation exists, I was commenting on the quality of it and the amount of reading you need to do to get up to speed on a basic element. If you have a great resource post it, a lot of people have these problems. (I take the fact your commend is coming ~ 3 months later as a very good example of that)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this redbook? Shows you end to end of how to do it.  http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpapers/pdfs/redp4885.pdf